# Why does it shows string index out of range while the characters are long enough?

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing, slice

Need some help to identify the issue here. I am trying to clean up a dataset using Pandas DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook.
My DataFrame data looks like this:
[Click here for the Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvOYx.png)

And I am trying to use for loop to filter and remove the rows which do not contain anything with 'B', 'R', 'T', or 'L' at index 11 of each string from the df2["Data"] column.

```
for unit in df2["Data"]:
    if unit[11] != "B":
        if unit[11] != "R":
            if unit[11] != "T":
                if unit[11] != "L":
                    df2.drop(df2.index[df2['Data'] == unit], inplace = True)
```

However it prompts this error saying that "string index out of range", while if you look at the string, for example "Calculator BW_2_1: Number\ttt" it is clearly more than 11 characters, but any idea why does it still prompt such an error?

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e1d0470b9bfb> in <module>
      1 for unit in df2["Data"]:
----> 2     if unit[11] != "B":
      3         if unit[11] != "R":
      4             if unit[11] != "T":
      5                 if unit[11] != "L":

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` accessor and `isin`:

```
df2 = df2[df2['Data'].str[11].isin(list('BRTL'))]
print(df2)

# Output
                   Data
1         Calculator BW
```

Setup:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['Calculator DienInTol', 'Calculator BW']})
print(df2)

# Output
                   Data
0  Calculator DienInTol
1         Calculator BW
```

Step by step:

```
# Extract the eleventh character
>>> df2['Data'].str[11]
0    D
1    B
Name: Data, dtype: object

# Check if the character is in the list ['B', 'R', 'T', 'L']
>>> df2['Data'].str[11].isin(list('BRTL'))
0    False
1     True
Name: Data, dtype: bool

# Keep rows where the condition is true
>>> df2[df2['Data'].str[11].isin(list('BRTL'))]
            Data
1  Calculator BW
```

Note: `list('BRTL')` create the list `['B', 'R', 'T', 'L']`.

Comment: Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I don't quite understand about this part, df2['Data'].str[11] how does it check on every value under df2['Data] since there is no for loop?
The idea is to loop through each and every value under ['Data], and check if they contain 'B' in their position 11; If yes, they will be included in the output Dataframe; If no, that whole corresponding row will be excluded (or deleted).

Comment: @Anthony. I updated my answer (and fixed it) with a step by step. You don't need loop because the operation can be vectorized. Consider this operations are executed in parallel without the need to execute them sequentially.